# LZW TIFF decoding

Tags: scala, tiff, lzw

When decoding tiff files with LZW decompression, the first 9 bits in the encoded bitstream should be "256", the clear-code.

But when I read it I get a 128, which I just can't figure out. I created the file with GDAL.

My code reading the file is:

```
val res = (for {
  i <- 0 until next
  if (bitSet.get(i + index))
  } yield (1 << i)).sum
```

The index is the index in the encoded bitstream and next is how many bits I should read (starting with 9).

So my question is why do I read an 128 instead of an 256? When printing the bitstream input the first bit that is set as 1 is bit number 8 (index 7).

The file in question is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42266515/aspect_lzw.tif

Thanks!

Comment: Post a sample file and I'll tell you what I find

Comment: I have now posted the file in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for posting the sample image. There's nothing wrong with the image; the first code is 0x100 (256). You must remember that TIFF LZW is encoded in "Motorola" byte order. The first two bytes of the file are 0x80 0x00. In binary, it's 10000000 00000000. The first 9 bits (when looking in the correct order) are 100000000 which is 256. You must gather the bytes in big-endian order and then you'll be able to decode it correctly. Here is a sample byte stream:

```
If the data from the file is: 0x80 0x01 0x25 0x43 0x7E

The bits are (laid out in big-endian order)
10000000 00000001 00100101 01000011 01111110

Taking 9-bit codes from this bitstream will get you:
100000000 (256), 000000100 (4), 100101010 (298), ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this answer. I've been going crazy over this. Let me just test it and then I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, one more question, if the bits were 000000011 what would that be? would it be 257?

Comment: 000000011 can be either 3 or 384 depending on the order you're reading.

Comment: Okay but then in "LZW" it's always 384 then?

Comment: What I mean is that the first byte is 0x80 right, and the second one is 0x10, what is that in "LZW"?

Comment: If the first byte is 0x80 (10000000) and the second byte is 0x10 (00010000), then the first code is 100000000 (256) and the second code is 0010000xx (the xx is 2 bits from the 3rd byte).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0x80 and 0x1, sorry

Comment: I mean if I'm reading 9 bits, what is 0x80 and 0x1? Because that would give me 10000000 00000001 which should also be 256? Since the first 9 bits are 100000000?

Comment: Yes, the high bit of the second byte is the low bit of your first 9-bit code, so the 9 bit code will still be 256 and the LSB of the second byte will become bit 2 (starting from 0) of the second 9-bit code. See my edit above for more clarity...